# Qt OpenGL Error

Tags: qt

I am following a simple OpenGL with Qt tutorial, but I have hit a snag. Here is the link to the tutorial:
[Link](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/175/support/Tutorial.pdf)

In the tutorial you add a container widget to the window and promote it to a class that is inherits QGLWidget. When I first ran the project I got an error at this line:

```
MyPanelOpenGL::MyPanelOpenGL(QObject *parent) :
QGLWidget(parent)
 {
    sides = 3;
    radius = 1.0;
  }
```

The error stated that it could convert QObject to a QWidget. This code is the constructor for the QGLWidget. I changed the argument to QWidget, but I got another error, this time in my ui.h file. The error is as follows:

```
/home/computer/build-OpenGLTest-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_GCC_64bit-Debug/ui_mainwindow.h:64: error: undefined reference to `MyPanelOpenGL::MyPanelOpenGL(QObject*)'
```

I changed the declaration when I changed the implementation in the panel's.h file. Here is the MyPanelOpenGL.h file:

```
#include <QGLWidget>

 class MyPanelOpenGL : public QGLWidget
 {
Q_OBJECT
 public:
   explicit MyPanelOpenGL(QWidget *parent = 0);
 protected:
void initializeGL();
void resizeGL(int w, int h);
void paintGL();
  private:
  int sides;
double radius;
 public slots:
void changeSides(int s);
void changeRadius(double r);

 };
```

Does anyone know what's going on? Thanks!

Comment: Please include in your post contents of `MyPanelOpenGL.h` file (only constructors should matter).

Comment: Ok I have added the .h file contents

Comment: The error is occurring because the header created by the `uic` is not aware of the `MyPanelOpenGL` header file.  Have you used this class as a promoted widget in the Designer, but neglected to tell it which header file to use?

Comment: Thanks cmannet85, you led my to working it out. I didn't fix my code until after I put the UI together in the designer, so I'm guessing the ui header wasn't up to date. I then deleted the old container widget and put a new one on. This ended up working.